# How to send checkbox checked data using jquery and ajax to struts action class

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

Below is my jquery here how to get the checkbox checked data in struts action class using jquery and ajax please tell me clearly

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
      responsive : true,
      "order":[],               
      "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": 0,
        "orderable": false,
        "className": "dt-center"
      }]                              
    });

    $("#selectall").click(function() {
      $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);               
        if ($('.case').prop('checked', this.checked)) {
          count = this.checked ? $(".case").length : 0;
          smsCount.innerHTML = count;
        }
      });           

      $(".case").click(function() {
        count = $(".case:checked").length;

        if ($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
          $("#selectall").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
          $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);
        }

        smsCount.innerHTML = count;
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

[Full coding with html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0vyR.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create your variable and getters and setters in the action class

```
private Boolean example;
public Boolean getExample() { return example; }
public void setExample(Boolean example) { this.example = example; }
```

Add value attribute to your checkbox(s)

`<input type="checkbox" class="case" value="true" name="example"/>`

Then use jquery's ajax() function to send it via a POST or GET

```
$.ajax({
    url: yoururl,
    method:'POST',
    data: $('.case').serialize()
});
```

When the request is submitted the example variable will be either true or false depending if the checkbox is checked or not.

Comment: The name is missing for the `input`-tag: `<input type="checkbox" class="case" value="true" name="example"/>`